# Burger menu doesn't display with CSS, JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I ran into a problem displaying a burger menu for my website. I wanted it to appear on the top right corner but somehow the menu is invisible right now.

[image: the burger menu should have been in the area circled blue]

I leave my source codes so I appreciate it if any of you could advise me on this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".burger").on("click", function(){
        $("nav li").toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

```css
/* Header */
header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #c6c1c1;
  background-color: white;
}

header .content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.875rem;
}


header .site-logo {
  flex: 1;
  width: 60%
}

header nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  padding-inline-start: 40px;
}

nav li {
  padding-left: 3.5rem;
}

nav li:last-child {
  display: flex;
}

nav a {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #de6cb6;
}

nav a:link {
  color: red;
}

nav select {
  display: none;
}

a:-webkit-any-link {
  cursor: pointer;
}

header .icon {
  width: 1rem;
  padding-left: .75rem;
  color: #de6cb6
}

header .mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  
  nav li:last-child {
    display: block;
  }

  header .content {
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  header {
    float: none;
  }

  header .desktop {
    display: none;
  }

  header .mobile {
    background: pink;
    color: pink;
    List-style: none;
    clear: both;
    }
    
  header .mobile li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  }
    
  header .mobile .burger {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background: pink;
  margin: 6px 0;
  }
    
  #burger {
  float: right;
  visibility: visible;
  margin: 5px;
  }

  header .content {
    padding: .5rem 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Header -->
  <header>
    <div class="content" style="height: 60px;">
      <a href="landingde.html"  class="site-logo"><img src="./resources/images/cropped_springtribelogo_notagline.png" style="height:60px;"></a>
      <nav class="desktop">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html">EN</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/springtribe.de/?hl=en"><img class="icon" src="./resources/images/instagram (1.png"></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/florian-zejewski-03653b164/?originalSubdomain=de"><img class="Linkedin" src="./resources/images/Linkedin_saturated_4.png" style="width: 20px; color: #de6cb6; margin-left: 8px;"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <nav class="mobile">
      <!-- Navigation Burger-->
      <div id="burger" class="burger">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>

      <br>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Page1</li>
      <li>Page2</li>
      <li>Page3</li>

      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: By the hamburger, do you mean Imprint, DE, and the Instagram and LinkedIn logos? Because I see them from Firefox render of iPhone 6, 7, 8.

Comment: Ok I should have said that way. I wanted to incorporate these items into a burger, but I forgot to include all of them into the burger div in my HTML. That's why you see About, Page 1, Page 3 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two issues in your code. Firstly the rules in the <1000px media query don't override the default `display: none` setting of the `header .mobile` element. Secondly you're applying the styling for the lines of the burger icon to the `.burger` div directly, instead of this child div within it. If you fix the following two issues, the code works correctly:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  header .mobile {
    /* other rules... */
    background-color: transparent;
    display: block;
  }

  /* OLD: header .mobile .burger { */
  header .mobile .burger div {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background: pink;
    margin: 6px 0;
}
```

Working example:

```css
/* Header */
header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #c6c1c1;
  background-color: white;
}

header .content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.875rem;
}

header .site-logo {
  flex: 1;
  width: 60%
}

header nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  padding-inline-start: 40px;
}

nav li {
  padding-left: 3.5rem;
}

nav li:last-child {
  display: flex;
}

nav a {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #de6cb6;
}

nav a:link {
  color: red;
}

nav select {
  display: none;
}

a:-webkit-any-link {
  cursor: pointer;
}

header .icon {
  width: 1rem;
  padding-left: .75rem;
  color: #de6cb6
}

header .mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  nav li:last-child {
    display: block;
  }
  header .content {
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  header {
    float: none;
  }
  header .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  header .mobile {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: pink;
    List-style: none;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
  }
  header .mobile li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  header .mobile .burger div {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background: pink;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
  #burger {
    float: right;
    visibility: visible;
    margin: 5px;
  }
  header .content {
    padding: .5rem 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="content" style="height: 60px;">
    <a href="landingde.html" class="site-logo"><img src="./resources/images/cropped_springtribelogo_notagline.png" style="height:60px;"></a>
    <nav class="desktop">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">EN</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/springtribe.de/?hl=en"><img class="icon" src="./resources/images/instagram (1.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/florian-zejewski-03653b164/?originalSubdomain=de"><img class="Linkedin" src="./resources/images/Linkedin_saturated_4.png" style="width: 20px; color: #de6cb6; margin-left: 8px;"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav class="mobile">
      <div id="burger" class="burger">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div><br>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Page1</li>
        <li>Page2</li>
        <li>Page3</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

As an aside, note that your HTML isn't valid as the `li` elements need to be children of a `ul`